# Is there a way to save [[Promise Result]] as a state variable in the 'index.js'page?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-redux, state, es6-promise

I tried to get Array from asynchronous call in 'index.js' file.

```
// index.js

const loadItem = async () => {
  const items = await axios.get("https://api.example.com")
    .then(res => {
      return res.data
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('error')
    });
  console.log([items])       // Array(25)
  return [items]
};
loadItem()


//And want to put this result value to in initstate(to make reducer) as below.



const initState = loadItem();

function reducer(state=initState, action) {
  return state
}
```

But, after "**console.log(props.state)**" at **App.js page**, I can see the result below

```
// App.js

Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(25)
```

In this case, how can I access the [PromiseResult] **as a state value**?

(I'd like to put this **Array** value as a **initState value** in 'index.js' page)

I hope to use this Array, but I can't find the way to access this PromiseResult state.

Comment: You can't access the value directly.  You use `await` or `.then()` on the promise to get a value from a promise.  Those are the only two ways to get the value out.  The thing about a promise is that you never know when the value is actually in the promise so you use `.then()` or `await` to get the value.  If the value is already there, those will give you the value nearly immediately.  If the value isn't there yet (the promise is still pending), they will notify you when the value is there.  This is how promises work.  There are no other ways to use a promise.

Comment: Make your initial state an empty array and just update it when the promise finishes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that using "await" or ".then()" on the promise ! 

I used both! thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can put initState as an empty Array first and dispatch an action to update the state when data come back from the api call like this

```
// reducer.js

const initState = []

function reducer(state=initState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
      case "UPDATE_DATA": return action.data
      default: return state
  }

}


// index.js
const loadItem = async () => {
  try{
      const items = await axios.get("https://api.example.com")
      console.log([items])       // Array(25)
      dispatch({action: "UPDATE_DATA", data: items})
  } catch(e){
    console.log('error')
  }
};
loadItem()
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice! 

As you say, I tried and understand the code line by line ! but it's not working and I can't find where I should fix

in the "try" code, it return Array(25) well, but the result is "error" ("catch" block returned)
Where can I modify in this code? Could you help me!